# started making character with his pose, now mirror doesn't work properly

Tags: mirror

So I made a character without using mirror and placed him in a certain pose. Now I want to sculpt it with a mirror, but the mirror itself is mirroring something else. 
On the screenshot you can see that the single blue dot should be on the other side of the head, but it's not. That's because at the start I deformed the head.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your scale and rotation with hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  before you start sculpting.

Comment: I tried your solution, yet the problem still persists.

Comment: Do you have modifiers on your mesh?

Comment: Yes, I do have them applied.

Comment: If you are still struggling with this it'll be easier to just upload your file, so people can better help you. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: blend files can't be larger than 30mb, and my blend exceeds that number.

Comment: Disable the modifiers and see what changes happen or just scrap it and start over.